# MBP Dual core (2006) fans usage since Mac OS X update 10.6.7

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, temperature

Am I the only one who noticed this :

since the last Mac OS X System update, the fans are quite often spinning at full speed, regardless of the activity on the computer. It happens even when there is not app running. I don't know if it's an heating problem or just the fans that are randomly triggered...

Does someone else encountered this weird behavior since a couple of months ?

EDIT : In fact, it seems that this problem has nothing to do with OS X upgrade. The problem is an heating problem and it related to some flash video reader that takes all the CPU power to display the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash also gets my MacBook's fans blowing after just a couple of minutes. I block it in my browser, but still need it sometimes. Not sure that anything's changed, though new versions of the Flash player (and the one built into Chrome) have certainly come out.

**[FlashBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofhjkjmkpinhpoiabjplobcaignabnl)** is your friend for Chrome, **[ClickToFlash](http://clicktoflash.com/)** is your friend for Safari, and **[a different FlashBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/)** is your friend for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow are certainly dirty. You can check it by opening your MBP. Find your model at [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Info/ID-your-Mac/474) and follow guides to access right and left fans.

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight also revs up the fans.  Usually this means that something is writing to your filesystem.  Instantly check Chrome/Chromium when this happens, is my advice.